# ADAL Angular2 appid missing in JWT token (Unauthorized response)

Tags: angular, azure, angular2-services, adal

I'm using ADAL library in Agular2 project to authenticate user against Azure AD, once user authenticated calling WebAPI to get some information using REST call. All these working fine with AngularJS-AzureAD-WebAPI scenario.

Followed MS article to create a sample project https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/04/26/using-adal-with-angular2

WebAPI receiving calls sfrom Angular2 project but, request has authorization token as anonymous. After futher reasearch, realized that JWT missing appid value and also aud property holds GUID which is Application ID.

Working Call JWT: (AngularJS to WebAPI)

**appid**: GUID for native application registered in Azure 
**aud**: someone.onmicrosoft.com/CortanaWebAPI

Not working call JWT: (Angular2 to webAPI)

**appid**: no entry for this property 
**aud**: GUID for native application registered in Azure

**adal configuration**

```js
const endpoints = {
“https://localhost:44383/”: “http://someone.onmicrosoft.com/CortanaWebAPI”
};
public get getAdalConfig(): any {
return {
tenant: ‘someone.onmicrosoft.com’,
clientId: ‘9d9cd8dd-087a-4e87-b3f9-6e7ded2b5e82’,
redirectUri: window.location.origin + ‘/’,
postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin + ‘/’,
endpoints: endpoints
};
}
```

Not sure why this is happening, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The is issue is not relative to the type of client you were developing. It depends on which token you were developing(id_token or access_token).

AFAIK, there is no `appid` claim is issued only in the access_token. To fix this issue, you need to get the **access_token** instead of **id_token**. And the `aud` claim is depends on the **resource** or **scope** parameter when you send the request for the token. Please cofig the corresponding `aud` in your web API project.

Comment: Web API is registered in Azure as APi application and Angular2 as native app. I guess I am stuck at injecting HTTP service to adal service, not sure how to do it in Angular2 project. Or it could be related to "ProtectedResourceInterceptor" not adding to adal service. I'm using this sample code https://github.com/vsaroopchand/angular2-seed

Comment: Yes, the code sample in the link doesn't inject the access token. You can refer the code sample [here](https://github.com/VitorX/angular2-adaljs-graph) which call the Azure AD Graph. Please feel free to let me know if you have the problem.